# Char pointers in C and multiple references to same address

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, c-strings

Having worked with python before, I am having trouble understanding char pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>          // 1
main()                      // 2
{                           // 3
    char *str1 = "Good";    // 4
    char *str2;             // 5
    str2 = str1;            // 6
    printf("1. str1 = %s, str2 = %s\n", str1, str2);   // 7
    str2 = "Bad";                                      // 8
    printf("2. str1 = %s, str2 = %s\n", str1, str2);   // 9
}                                                      // 10
```

According to my understanding,
In line 4: str1 holds the address of str1[0] (i.e. &str1[0])
In line 6: str2 is made to point towards &s[0] (since, str1 holds &str1[0])
In line 8: value at str2 is changed to 'Bad'. 
But, since str2 points to &s[0], str1 should also change to 'Bad'.

Comment: You've made some edits, so I assume by 'q', you mean 'str2'.  When you write 'str2="Bad"', you are changing str2 to point to a different location.  You are not changing the content at the location pointed to by str2.

Comment: I made the necessary edits. @Lundin

Comment: Try changing `str2 = "Bad"` to `strcpy(str2, "Bad)` to understand what's going on. In your original example, that line changes str2 to point to a static string created at compile time.

Comment: Ahem. `strcpy(str2, "Bad")` is obviously what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pointer is basically what its name suggests. A pointer variable, like str1 only 
*points* to &st1[0].

```
*str1 -> &str1[0]
 str2 = str1
```

This makes str2 also point to &str1[0]. But it is just pointing to that memory address. 
So when you write

```
str2 = "Bad"
```

"Bad" is a string in memory which has its own new address. And you are using the pointer variable to point to this new place.

To actually update the memory address that the pointer variable points to you have to use it like this

```
*str2 = "Bad"
```

When you use str2, you are using the variable. But when, *str2 you are actually using the underlying address that the variable str2 currently points to.

Answer (score 1):

After the execution of

```
str2 = "Bad";
```

str2 points to a different location.  It no longer references the same memory that str1 does.  This statement does not change the content of the memory pointed at by the former value of str2.